# How to copy the text button present in a particular textview to clipboard when a button is pressed?

Tags: android

How to copy the text present in a particular text view to clipboard when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

try below code on button click

```
String stringcopy = textView.getText().toString();
int startIndex = textView.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = textView.getSelectionEnd();
stringcopy = stringcopy.subString(startIndex, endIndex);
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.setText(stringcopy);
```